# Isn't it inappropriate for Dax to touch Quark's ears?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

My DS9 memory is very hazy but I'm sure I can remember a number of instances where Dax or perhaps Kira persuade Quark by rubbing his ears.

If memory serves then Oo-mox is a Ferengi sex thing. If that's the case then isn't it entirely inappropriate for a Federation officer to persuade him by rubbing his ears?

Comment: It's the equivalent of giving a human male a shoulder-rub. Sensual, but not necessarily sexual.

Comment: If you've never seen one human persuade another human by exerting their sexuality... you must have shared that AHCH-TO planet with that Luke Skywalker solitary monk :)  Why would people in the Federation be any different than humans now?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Isn't the entire premise of Star Trek that humans in the future have progressed to be quite different from the humans of today?

Comment: He... seemed okay with it.

Answer (score 8):

## It could be argued that such behaviour is inappropriate

The (non-canon) book *[Vulcan's Forge](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Vulcan's_Forge_%28novel%29)* notes the following Starfleet Regulation:

> Regulation 256.15: "Officers shall show professional behavior at all times."

([Source](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_General_Orders_and_Regulations))

Now, it's important to note that [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Oo-mox) does clarify that Oo-mox was:

> Not strictly sexual

Nevertheless:

> It could be very distracting for a Ferengi and may often be employed by females or males of other species in order to **distract a Ferengi** during negotiations or to **coerce him into an action he would otherwise avoid.** (DS9: "Facets")

Whether you consider this course of action to be 'unprofessional', I'll leave it up to you.  If you do though, then you could definitely say such action would be 'inappropriate' with regards to Starfleet Regulations!

Comment: It should nonetheless be noted that beside the "not strictly sexual" remark, the linked article also mentions "the Ferengi ear was a major erogenous zone" and that oo-mox is of "semi-erotic nature". Furthermore, the behind-the-scenes box likens "oo-mox by [one]self" to masturbation. Finally, do note that the sentence that contains the "not strictly sexual" remark may use *sexual* in the biological sense (i.e. oo-mox has no biological function in terms of sexuality), which does not mean that it is not still an erotic act. In particular, being "a means to an end" does not exclude that.

Comment: There is a moment in one episode when Quark tells Jadzia to not touch his ears unless she is serious. I believe it was during one of their Tongo games.

Comment: “Memory Alpha does clarify that Oo-mox was not strictly sexual” — maybe it’s a bit like [ASMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_sensory_meridian_response).